# Why does ImageResizer crop tiff pages if the tiff has pages of differing sizes?

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I'm using imageresizer.net in a console app to pull pages out of tiff images, but when the tiff contains pages of differing sizes, imageresizer seems to treat all the pages as having the same dimensions as the first page.

In my test, if the first page is A4 and the second is A3, the biggest part of page 2 that I can get is A4 (the left-hand side of the image is output and the right-hand side is truncated). No error is raised by imageresizer either.

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(sourceImagePath, destinationImagePath, new ResizeSettings("page=2"));
```

Am I missing something, or does imageresizer.net not handle this scenario?

Comment: I believe it's a GDI+ bug; you might try WicDeocder instead.

Comment: If you can provide an example file under the public domain, we can set up regression tests for this.

Comment: I changed the bit `new ResizeSettings("page=2")` to `new ResizeSettings("page=2&decoder=wic")` with no difference in output.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist provided me an updated ImageResizer.dll which seems to handle this issue correctly. I have put an example tiff [here](http://min.us/mLRYXi1c7), with my outputs using the two different dll versions (v3.2.2.0 and v3.2.3.766). Not sure what to do with this question now, as the new version has fixed my problem.

Comment: Once I release 3.2.3 publicly I'll post an answer with a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks for reporting this bug!**

This bug occurred because image dimensions were being cached prior to setting the active frame or page.

**It has been fixed in [release 3.2.3 (changelog)](http://imageresizing.net/releases/3-2-beta-3)**.

You can [find the latest download here](http://imageresizing.net/download).